# Getting poor results using MinMaxScaler, am i using the fuction wrong?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a array in float 32 with values, and I seem to be getting the wrong result from the sklearn minMaxScaler function.

```
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
print(values)
[[ 1.  2.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  3.  4.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  0.  0.]]
In [34]:

# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
print(scaled)
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
In [28]:
```

Am i using the function wrong? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

MinMaxScaler scales per column. So your result is correct. In the first column, for example, the minimum (1) is replaced with 0 and the maximum (2) with 1, as expected

Comment: What would be the proper way to normalize all my data then?

Comment: Why MinmaxScaler result not suitable for you? What do you want to achieve? Please extend your question

Comment: I'm trying to normalize my data, and I was following a tutorial that said to use minmaxscaler, but I ended up using the normalize function from sklearn, and it worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2162942 `normalize()` function from scikit will normalize the row. So please double check the output values. Are you sure you want that?